# Publishing an ARP entry

Tags: ip, mac-address, arp, spoofing

I'm experimenting with a spoofed IP connection, as described in section 7 of this article ([IP SPOOFING with BSD RAW SOCKETS INTERFACE](http://www.enderunix.org/docs/en/rawipspoof/)). Indeed, when a SYN is sent with no regard for ARP, there's no response. One of the two solutions presented in the article (should be the simpler) is to add a static ARP entry to the client host. My host is configured as 10.1.1.10 and I want the spoofed IP address to be 10.1.1.20.

To add the new entry, I ran:

```
# arp -i enp4s2 -Ds 10.1.1.20 enp4s2 pub
```

and when I run `arp -n`, it shows:

```
10.1.1.20     *      *          MP            enp4s2
```

From the server, I tried to `arping 10.1.1.20` and there is no reply from the client host (with the published ARP entry).

Probably I didn't understand how ARP publishing works. Literature on the net seems to be very simplified on this matter.

My distro is an OpenSuSE and the kernel version is 3.16.7-21-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT.

Comment: The spoofed IP also needs to be configured on an interface on the spoofer.

Comment: Both addresses are in the same subnet. Is this safe to do?

Comment: Yep. You'll want to add it to the loop back interface.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Could you please answer the question with the missing steps (commands) ? So I could try them and things will be clear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether that command still works on *BSD, but seems to have been broken on linux for over a decade. These days [arp_req_set_public()](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/arp.c?h=v3.6#n982) punts to [arp_req_set_proxy()](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/arp.c?h=v3.6#n969), which triggers the kernel **proxy_arp** mechanism. I gather that ARP publishing was intended as a means of implementing proxy ARP, later rendered obsolete by an easier, less accident-prone, and more capable implementation.

It's a shame though. ARP publishing would have had other uses - a convenient way to handle dedicated NAT pools, for one. If you really need the semantics that are promised by the arp manual, you could try a userland ARP daemon like **honeynet arpd** (a.k.a. farpd) or **choparpd**.